# Linq возвращает IEnumerable вместо IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .netcore2.0

Заметил что Linq в .net core 2.0 возвращает IEnumerable, вместо привычного IQueryable, работать с EF можно, но если в БД будет 2 миллиона записей и они выгрузятся в память будет - плохо. В решения только нашёл подключить:  [System.Linq.Queryable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Queryable/). Но это не помогает, так как я не нашёл способа выкосить старый Linq.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из какого метода IEnumerable возвращается вместо IQueryable?

Comment: Приведите ваш код.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "выкосить старый Linq"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не так сказал, извините, удалить ссылку на System.Linq.Enumerable

Comment: @Алексей а зачем ее удалять?

Comment: @PavelMayorov решение было в том чтобы заменить одну библиотеку на другую, якобы мы удаляем ссылки System.Linq.Enumerable и подставляем System.Linq.Queryable

Comment: @Алексей достаточно добавить System.Linq.Queryable. Удалять-то зачем?

Comment: @PavelMayorov потому-что методы от туда возвращают IEnumerable (http://prntscr.com/is0lny ), хоть и все dll присутствуют (http://prntscr.com/is0mdx )

Comment: @Алексей и что дальше? Они не мешают же.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Окей, если они не мешают, и всё в порядке, то почему Where возвращает IEnumerable<> если DbSet<> унаследован от IQueryable<> ? Что не так я делаю?

Comment: @Алексей магия, однако. Нужны подробности.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74629/discussion-between--and-pavel-mayorov).

Comment: покажите пожалуйста весь код метода (не скриншот)

Comment: не стоит задавать один и тот же вопрос дважды. если хотите добавить деталей - отредактируйте старый вопрос

Comment: и да, вам стоит привести код метода - т.к. по скриншоту угадать можно, но не 100%

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Полного кода метода нет, так что ответ наугад:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> = dbSet.Where(predicate);
```

Скорее всего `predicate` объявлен как

```
Func<TEntity, bool> predicate = ...
```

Дело в том, что метод `Queryable.Where` принимает не `Func<TEntity, bool>`, а `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`.

А вот метод `Enumerable.Where` принимает просто `Func<TEntity, bool>`.

`Func<TEntity, bool>` - это просто делегат, который принимает `TEntity` и возвращает `bool`. Внутри делегата может быть любой метод с подходящей сигнатурой.

Если вы напишете

```
Func<TEntity, bool> predicate = e => e.Id > 5;
```

то компилятор просто создаст метод вида

```
bool someMethod(TEntity e)
{
    return e.Id > 5;
}
```

Этот делегат можно вызывать, но вот залезть внутрь делегата, достать оттуда содержимое метода и как-то его превратить в SQL не получится. Поэтому делегата достаточно для `Enumerable`, но не для `Queryable`.

---

`Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` - это объект, а не метод.

Если вы напишете в коде

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = e => e.Id > 5;
```

то компилятор развернет это примерно в

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda(
                Expression.MakeBinary(
                     ExpressionType.Equal,
                     Expression.PropertyAccess("e", "Id"),
                     Expresison.Const("5")....
```

и вот такое дерево объектов LINQ-провайдер легко может разобрать и превратить в соответствующий код SQL.

---

Обычно в коде для работы с LINQ используют лямбды. Лямбды компилируются или в анонимные методы, или в деревья выражений, в зависимости от контекста. При этом дерево выражений считается предпочтительным вариантом. Т.е. если вы напишете

```
dbSet.Where(e => e.Id == 5);
```

то компилятор предпочтет перегрузку с `Expression` и, соответственно, механизм `IQueryable`. Но т.к. вы явно задали тип предиката как `Func` - вы принудительно выбрали `IEnumerable`.

Поменяйте тип у `predicate` на `Expression<>` и все будет ок.

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать фильтрацию по Where, она будет выполнена на серверной стороне, и ничего лишнего выгружено не будет.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Where(b => b.Url.Contains("dotnet"))
    .ToList();
}
```

Этот код сгенерирует SQL с условием WHERE blogs.Url LIKE '%dotnet%' и выполнит его на стороне бд в момент перечисления массива. В приведённом коде это произойдёт в момент вызова .ToList();

Почитайте [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/querying/overview)

Comment: да, но это сработает в случае вызова `Queryable.Where`, а не `Enumerable.Where`. На этой особенности основана локализация запросов в репозитории - возвращать IEnumerable, и тогда внешний код не сможет построить несовместимые с базой запросы.

Comment: @PashaPash `DbSet<>.Where` должен `IQueryable` возвращать

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин а все равно что он возвращает. Where - это метод расширения. IQueryable унаследован от IEnumerable, если компилятор не увидит класс System.Linq.Queryable, но увидит  System.Linq.Enumerable, то вызовется статический метод  System.Linq.Enumerable.Where, который создаст WhereEnumerableIterator и переберет все в памяти.

Comment: @PashaPash таких тонкостей не знал, но значит в данном случае имеет место что компилятор не видит `IQueryable`...

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин в обычном .net и System.Linq.Queryable и System.Linq.Enumerable лежат в System.Core, т.е. или они оба есть, или их обоих нет. Компилятор предпочитает методы из System.Linq.Queryable т.к. в них параметры луче соответствуют вызову. В .net core System.Linq.Queryable лежит в System.Linq.Queryable.dll, если ее отключить - компилятор увидит только методы из System.Linq.Enumerable, лямбды скомпилирутся в анонимные методы, а не в деревья выражений, и Where отработает на стороне C#.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74619/discussion-on-answer-by-anton-shakalo-linq--ienumerable--iquerya).