# Как в Linq To Entities использовать кастомные сторонние функции?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

У меня есть вот такой код

```
var articles = db.Articles.Where(x => CheckIfGood(x.Title)).ToList();

public bool CheckIfGood(string title)
{
     return title.Length > 3;
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку

> Выражению LINQ to Entities не удается распознать метод "Boolean
>   CheckIfGood(System.String)", поэтому его нельзя преобразовать в
>   выражение хранилища.

Конечно пример немного надуманный, но в реальности много раз пытался свои функции использовать внутри лямбд в EF, безрезультатно.

Как можно сделать что бы этот код заработал, или такое вообще не предполагается в EF?

Comment: Сам EF преобразует все в аналогичный SQL запрос, но он не может это сделать для кастомной функции и потому возникает такая проблема. Можно попробовать написать кастомные выражения через Expression и подсовывать их в EF, но я этого не пробовал.

Comment: @AlexKrass можно примерчик, пока непонятно как, то есть идея понятна, но как сделать пока не понял.

Comment: Конечно это немного странно, но у меня отработал такой код, делаем Expression: `Expression<Func<EnglishDictionary, bool>> ex = s => CheckIfGood(s);` и подсовываем скомпилированную версию в EF: `var result = DB.GetInstance().EnglishDictionary.Where( ex.Compile() ).ToList();`. Правда думаю, если внутри сторонней функции будет что-то сложное, он упадет.

Comment: @AlexKrass да,у меня тоже заработало, магия какая-то )) причём работает именно с `Compile`

Comment: @AlexKrass нет там никакой магии. `Compile()` компилирует выражение типа `Expression<Func<EnglishDictionary, bool>> ` в анонимный метод типа `Func<EnglishDictionary, bool>`. Это приводит к тому, что вызывается `Enumerable.Where` вместо `Queryable.Where` - т.е. из базы выбираются все объекты и для них отрабатывает Linq to objects. По сути, это то же самое что сделать `db.Articles.ToList().Where(x => CheckIfGood(x.Title)).ToList();`. Я буквально вчера подробно отвечал на похожий вопрос (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/799421/177221), и Дмитрий Полянин там был.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин можно объяснить EF как ваша функция отображается в SQL (DbFunctionAttribute + кастомный IStoreModelConvention, что-то вроде https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/registering-sql-server-built-in-functions-to-entity-framework-code-first). Но не настолько глубоко лез EF, может есть варианты попроще. Или можно взять хак вроде https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler, и попытаться декомпилировать делегат обратно в дерево. Но мне это кажется не очень надежным хаком :)

Comment: @PashaPash так как раз из вашего ответа я и написал свой вопрос, решил разобраться с темой, которую уже давно не мог решить

Comment: @PashaPash ктстаи есть какой-то легальный способ скомпилировать запросы в базу данных, читал про него, но не смотрел ещё как это делается, конечно не говорю что это поможет.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин в каком смысле легальный? :) увидеть какой запрос получится из конкретного Query? Скорее всего есть, но сорри, я не лез так глубоко в EF. Написать свой провайдер, который сам соберет SQL (или не SQL, а, скажем OData фильтр) - да, достаточно просто, если поддерживать только базовые вещи.

Comment: @PashaPash вот это имею ввиду - https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/8.1.php

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/351556/#comment_10718334