# Вывести содержимое List во view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Каким образом можно вывести выборку на основе модели данных. но с полями в ней не описанными?
Например имеется контроллер:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var asd = db.tbl
            .GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.q_Date))
            .Select (x => new
                  {
                  Val = x.Count(),
                  Dat = (DateTime)x.Key
                  }).ToList();   
        ViewBag.Asd = asd;
        return View();
    }
```

здесь tbl таблица с полем q_Date.

Но данную выборку не получается вывести во view:

```
@foreach (var c in ViewBag.Asd)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @c.Dat
        </td>
        <td>
            @c.Val
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Ошибка - "object" не содержит определения для "Dat" : @c.Dat
Неужели для каждого такого случая придется создавать отдельный класс в Models? нельзя это как-то обойти?

Comment: не используйте ViewBag

Comment: А как тогда вывести List<> во view? Если он не описан в Models?

Comment: Правильный подход - создать отдельный класс-модель. Или можно заюзать dynamic.

Comment: А если много таких List<> которые нужно выводить? Для каждого создавать отдельный класс? Или можно в одном описать все необходимые поля в пределах одного контроллера?

Comment: Да, создавать отдельный класс. [Using a Model to pass information to our View](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3#using-a-model-to-pass-information-to-our-view).

Comment: вот  @Alexander Petrov подсказывает так как надо сделать

Comment: вот так пробни `@foreach (dynamic c in ViewBag.Asd)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @c.Dat
        </td>
        <td>
            @c.Val
        </td>
    </tr>
}`

Comment: то есть object на dynamic  динамик  все что угодно содержти

Comment: >от так пробни @foreach (dynamic c in ViewBag.Asd) - 
Ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобные классы можно называть Dto, ViewModel - и складывать в отдельные от папки с моделями (если у вас единое приложение). Делайте примерно так:

Создаёте модель представления:

```
public class BookListViewModel
{
    public int Val { get; set; }

    public DateTime Dat { get; set; }
}
```

Делаете экшн контроллера вида:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = db.tbl
        .GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.q_Date))
        .Select (x => new
              {
                  V = x.Count(),
                  D = (DateTime)x.Key
              })
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select (x => new BookListViewModel
              {
                  Val = x.V,
                  Dat = (DateTime)x.D
              })
        .ToArray();
    return View(model);
}
```

(Тут надо хорошо понимать разницу между IEnumerable и IQueryable, см. например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863684/213987))

Ещё можно сделать конструктор в классе:

```
public class BookListViewModel
{
    public BookListViewModel (int val, DateTime dat)
    {
        this.Val = val;
        this.Dat = dat;
    }

    public int Val { get; private set; }

    public DateTime Dat { get; private set; }
}
```

И сократить запись до:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = db.tbl
        .GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.q_Date))
        .Select (x => new
              {
                  V = x.Count(),
                  D = (DateTime)x.Key
              })
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select (x => new BookListViewModel(x))
        .ToArray();
    return View(model);
}
```

Или вообще перейти на использование автомаппера.

В представлении итерируете модель:

```
@model IEnumerable<BookListViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Dat
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Val
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: (Под рукой нет готового проекта, так что если где ошибки -- сообщите мне, я как доберусь до студии поправлю)